# Python NLTK Prepare Data from CSV for Tokenization

Tags: python, csv, nltk, tokenize

I'm new to Python and NLTK. I'm trying to prepare text for tokenization using NLTK in Python after I import the text from a csv. There's only one column in the file with free text. I want to isolate that specific column, which I did.... I think.

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import re
import unicodedata


pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',50)

oiw = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\tgray\Documents\PythonScripts\Worksheets.csv')

text = oiw.drop(oiw.columns[[1,2,3]],axis=1)

for row in text:
    for text['value'] in row:
        tokens = word_tokenize(row)
print(tokens)
```

When I run the code, the output it gives me is ['values'] which is the column name. How do I get the rest of the rows to show up in the output?

Sample data I have in the 'values' column:

*The way was way too easy to order online.*

*Everything is great.*

*It's too easy for me to break.*

The output I'm hoping to receive is:

```
['The','way','was','too','easy','to','order','online','Everything','is','great','It''s','for','me','break']
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Added sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correction you need to be made is in the segment.

```
oiw = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\tgray\Documents\PythonScripts\Worksheets.csv')

text = oiw.drop(columns=[1,2,3]) # correctly dropping columns named 1 2 and 3 

for row in text['value']: # Correctly selecting the column 
    tokens = word_tokenize(row)
    print(tokens) # Will print tokens in each row
print(tokens) # Will print the tokens of the last row
```

Hence you will be iterating over the correct column of the dataframe.